# What is the minimum size a parking spot can be in the USA?

Tags: parking

What is the law stating the minimum size that a parking spot can be in the USA? For example in MN where I'm from.

The only reason why I ask is I was at a dealership that had smaller than normal parking spots compared to shopping centers.

Comment: Are they allowed different sizes compared to residential?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about maintenance or repair.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Law.SE, not here.

Comment: How can I revise the question so it does work?

Comment: No size limit, but most cities have laws about the number of parking spaces you must have for any given size of business.

Comment: so if all of the spots are for compact cars, and you have a full size but it's not marked, it's their fault? example a fiat dealership.